# Missing file from sfmc-sdk-ios - Hardcoded path to all-product-headers.yaml

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, xcode

When trying to debug our application via LLDB, when I try and print out a variable using `po object`, it reports an error saying that it can't find `all-product-headers.yaml`. Here's the specific error:

```
error: expression failed to parse:
error: virtual filesystem overlay file '/Users/eyehuda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarketingCloudSDK-hisiggctcgcrahehtsfqvxhdfinf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MarketingCloudSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MarketingCloudSDK.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MarketingCloudSDK.build/all-product-headers.yaml' not found
error: virtual filesystem overlay file '/Users/eyehuda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MarketingCloudSDK-hisiggctcgcrahehtsfqvxhdfinf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MarketingCloudSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MarketingCloudSDK.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MarketingCloudSDK.build/all-product-headers.yaml' not found

error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please check the above error messages for possible root causes.
```

It looks like that file was added with a hardcoded path when the framework was built? Is it possible to get the path to it corrected? I found a similar issue here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1628#issuecomment-771462320 with a potential solution.

We're running MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.10 from SPM with 1.0.6 from SFMCSDK.

Any ideas on a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to the latest version of SFMCSDK 1.0.8 and (if you're leveraging it) MarketingCloudSDK - 8.0.12